# Rails: Inconsistent behavior with link_to(..., remote: true) when using has_many relationship

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, has-many, helper

I am experiencing inconsistent behavior when using regular routing vs AJAX in a Rails app.  I have a link whose function is to destroy a `has_many :through` relationship.  When AJAX is not used, there is no problem.  When AJAX is used (i.e. remote: true) the link destroys the relationship as well as the owner object.

Here are the details:

I have a simple application with models `Reader`, `Book`, and `Favorite`.  A reader `has_many` books through favorites, and a book `has_many` readers through favorites. When I use the link to "Remove from Favorites", the book is also destroyed when AJAX is used.  This problem does not happen if I don't have remote:true.  Here is the server log:

```
Started DELETE "/favorites/5" for ::1 at 2016-01-22 08:06:03 -0800
Processing by FavoritesController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"5"}
  Favorite Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "favorites".* FROM "favorites" WHERE     "favorites"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  Book Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."id"     = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "favorites" WHERE "favorites"."id" = ?      [["id", 5]]
   (1.9ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/books/5
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)


Started DELETE "/books/5" for ::1 at 2016-01-22 08:06:03 -0800
Processing by BooksController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"5"}
  Book Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."id"     = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Favorite Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "favorites".* FROM "favorites" WHERE     "favorites"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 5]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "books" WHERE "books"."id" = ?  [["id", 5]]
   (0.9ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/books
Completed 302 Found in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)
```

Here is what I believe to be the relevant code:

book.rb

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites, class_name: "Favorite",
                    foreign_key: "book_id",
                    dependent: :destroy
  has_many :readers, through: :favorites
end
```

reader.rb

```
class Reader < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites, class_name: "Favorite",
                    foreign_key: "reader_id",
                    dependent: :destroy
  has_many :books, through: :favorites
  def add_favorite(book)
    return if Favorite.exists?(book_id:book.id,reader_id:self.id)
    favorites.create(book_id: book.id, reader_id: self.id)
    self.reload
  end
end
```

favorite.rb

```
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I have a 'link_to' on the books/show view that says "Add to Favorites" if there is no book-reader relationship and "Remove from Favorites" if there is a book-reader relationship.  The correct link is generated in a helper module.

books_helper.rb

```
module BooksHelper
  def favorites_link_for(reader, book)
    if reader && Favorite.exists?(book_id: book.id, reader_id:    reader.id)
      link_to("Remove From Favorites", Favorite.find_by(book_id: book.id, reader_id: reader.id), :method => 'delete', remote: true)

    elsif reader && !Favorite.exists?(book_id: book.id, reader_id: reader.id)
      link_to("Add To Favorites", favorites_path(book_id: book.id, reader_id: reader.id), :method => 'post', remote: true)
    end
  end
end
```

The only controller of interest is favorites_controller.rb:

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    reader = Reader.find(params[:reader_id])
    @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
    reader.add_favorite(Book.find(params[:book_id]))
    redirect_to @book
  end

  def destroy
    debugger
    fav = Favorite.find(params[:id])
    @book = Book.find(fav.book_id)
    fav.destroy
    redirect_to @book
  end
end
```

And the only view of interest is books/show:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @book.name %>
  <%= favorites_link_for(Reader.last, @book) %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_book_path(@book) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', books_path %>
```

The full code is available here:  https://github.com/JenDobson/rails-with-remote-issue/tree/broken  The Rails version is 4.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by having the line `redirect_to @book` in FavoritesController#destroy.  When I removed that line all worked fine.  That line needed to be modified anyway to allow for the different page responses under html and js, although I still don't understand why `redirect_to @book` causes the book record to be deleted under JS but not under HTML.  I'm happy to accept an answer from anyone who can further enlighten me on this.

The fixed controller looks like this:

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
def create
    @reader = Reader.find(params[:reader_id])
    @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
    @reader.add_favorite(Book.find(params[:book_id]))
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @book }
      format.js
    end
end

def destroy
    fav = Favorite.find(params[:id])
    @book = Book.find(fav.book_id)
    @reader = Reader.find(fav.reader_id)
    fav.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @book }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

The code on github has been fixed:  https://github.com/JenDobson/rails-with-remote-issue/tree/master